# Too large array dimensions when defining an array in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate the distance between every two points among ~1000 points in a map. While defining the distance arrays d[1000][1000], I got the error "code::blocks has stopped working".

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    double d[1000][1000];
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

I am working on 64bits PC and coding in Code::Blocks.

Comment: _"I got error"_ is too ambiguous. Please mention the exact error. Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: code::blocks has stopped working... while changing to a smaller array index, the error is gone

Comment: This is a very large array (8000000 bytes) or (7813 kB) or (7.6 MB) some platforms have only 1 MB of stack, you shoud say what platform is this and check the corresponding default stack size for it.

Comment: 'stopped working' is too ambiguous. Please mention the exact error. Then we will be able to help you.

Comment: @SongZhibo CodeBlocks itself stopped?

Comment: C'mon guys, quit being hard on him.  It is a stack overflow....  too biased against answering real questions from people who aren't just posting homework questions.

Comment: @RobL Someone already found a duplicate.

Comment: Are there any debugger configuration options in CodeBlocks that manage how exceptions. like stack overflow. are handled?

Comment: @iharob you are right. the real problem is that I can't think of an alternative way to define this distance array

Comment: @SongZhibo You will need `malloc()` and that is not very simple to use because you then will need `free()`. Also, consider using a struct to represent bidimensional data instead, it will not solve the problem but it will avoid further problems.

Comment: @RobL any framework worth it's hire should not just 'stop working' because an app being debugged generates a segfault/AV, eg. from stack overflow.

Comment: @iharob I have no problems in using malloc, but the question is that am I allowed using malloc() function in code::blocks?

Comment: @SongZhibo why not?  Try it!

Comment: It has nothing to do with code::blocks, `malloc()` is a standard library function for [tag:c] and [tag:c++] too.

Comment: ok thanks guys, I will delete this question later...sorry for trouble

Comment: It's a better solution than a global or static storage - such storage is not thrad-safe, you have a lot of data and may wish to thread off operations later;)

Comment: @SongZhibo NO!  Do not delete!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably are overflowing your stack.  This is creating an 8 megabyte array.  Making it global would probably solve your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

double d[1000][1000];

int main(){

...
return 0;
}
```

Edit: Of course, you could use malloc and free.  But, since this was clearly a beginner question, I avoided them.  And, because the array was created at the top of main, this specific case will be fine as a global since it is by definition already a singleton.

---

This (@iharob) is my answer: the question was closed again although I didn't like the answer to the other question. Perhaps this should be the duplicate to mark that one

---

You need to use `malloc()` if you want to use 2 index notation you need to create an array of pointers which is very differente from what you have in your code. The array of pointers would not store values contigously and would require confusing allocation deallocation code which in turn would make it very hard to manage errors too.

Depending on what you need, if you need points in a plane do it like this, since it's cleaner, and simpler to allocate/deallocate

```
struct Point 
{
    double x;
    double y;
};

struct Point *data;
data = malloc(1000 * sizeof(*data));
if (data == NULL)
    please_do_not_continue();
// Now you can access `data' like

data[0].x = 1;
data[0].y = 2;
```

If you really need it to be a 2 dimensional array, you can mimic that with the array of pointers (array of arrays if you will)

```
double **array;
array = malloc(1000 * sizeof(*array));
if (array == NULL)
    return handle_malloc_failure();
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 1000 ; ++i)
{
    array[i] = malloc(1000 * sizeof(**array));
    // See how handling errors now is very complicated
    if (array[i] == NULL)
        free_allocated_elements_and_return?();
}

// ...
```

Remember that you MUST `free()` this when you no longer need to access it, that would be by looping thourgh every pointer in the second case and finally `free()`ing the array of pointers. And simply `free(data)` in the first case.

Comment: I'd go for *malloc/calloc* instead (not the dv btw)

Comment: @iharob: If it is a stack overflow (which is *probably* the cause) then the proposed answer will definitely fix it.  Ergo, it will probably fix his problem because we don't know exactly what his problem was.

Comment: @iharob: that would prevent the issue because the memory is not allocated on the stack but in the data segment (bss section on Unix).  That is not affected by stack size issues.  It would be possible to use `malloc()` or a relative to allocate the memory from 'the heap' instead.  Both work.

Comment: I upvoted this because 1) it probably is SO, (despite the OP being so confusing) ,and 2) the OP is making noises about deleting the question:(

Comment: it worked by defining it a global variable!!! thanks!

Comment: @RobL Sorry, I used your answer since the question was closed again.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is why I was asking, I am not a computer scientist and I don't know these details. Thank you.

Comment: @iharob: np, this has all gotten kind of silly really quickly.  I just wish people would stop being so hostile to noobs who make an honest attempt at asking a question.

Comment: @RobL I understand, this is a very common thing on SO. And I don't like it either. In my opinion this was a very valid question.

Comment: I would mention another way to solve the problem (but too similar to merit another answer): make d a static local variable. This will only restrict d visibility, but it will be stored the same way as a global variable.